# CSS for Navbar does not work

Tags: html, css

I have an application on ruby on rails with a navbar - the part with the brand and project name can be changed by my stylesheet, but for the navbar-right part. I tried so many references: `.navbar-right` `nav navbar-nav ul li a` and all the parts of it and all the combinations of those and `.active` and without . and just ul, I can just not find which class or id I have to use to make my styles work on the right part.

Here's my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Julinsecommerce</title>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>

  <body>

    <!--navbar starts here-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>          
          <div class="projectName navbar-brand">
            <a href="./index">ДЖУЛИН</a>
          </div> <!--end projectName -->          
        </div> <!--end navbar-header -->        
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

          <ul class="navbar-right nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"> <a href="#home"> Home </a> </li> 
            <li class="active"> <a href="#about"> About </a></li> 
            <li class="active"> <a href="#contact">Contact </a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div> <!-- end nav container--> 
    </nav>

    <%= yield %>

    <footer>
       &copy; 2017 Julin
       <p> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span> 
       <a href=#> Back to top </a>  
    </footer>

  </body>

</html>
```

and my CSS:

```
    // Place all the styles related to the static_pages controller here.
// They will automatically be included in application.css.
// You can use Sass (SCSS) here: http://sass-lang.com/

html, 
body { 
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

/***navbar***/

.navbar {
    background-color: #28c093;
    height: 5em;
}

.navbar-collapse collapse .navbar-right ul li a {
    color: #3234cd;
    background-color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    }

.navbar-nav li a:hover {
        color: #ff0;
    }

.projectName a {
    color: #3234cd;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    padding-top: 1.1em;
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,Georgia,serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.projectName a:hover {
    color: #1d5fd7;
}

/***h1***/
h1 {
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,Georgia,serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #3234cd;
    text-align: center;
}

.img-responsive hoian {
    display: inline-block;
    float: center;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 2em;
    border: red;
}

body > .container {
  padding: 60px 15px 0;
}

/***footer***/
footer {
    padding-top: 1em;
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,Georgia,serif;
    color: #3234cd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the js `<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` under the

Answer (score 0):

**1st**. You don't have jQuery. **jQuery is required for bootstrap** (unless you are just using their style like grid system).

Add jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**2nd**. I suggest to use id instead of class for your navbar target `data-target="#my-navbar"`.

**3rd**. Target the `<a>` (that's where the content been hold) to add style like:

```
#my-navbar a {
  background: aqua;
}
```

```css
// Place all the styles related to the static_pages controller here.
// They will automatically be included in application.css.
// You can use Sass (SCSS) here: http://sass-lang.com/
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 60px;
}


/***navbar***/

.navbar {
  background-color: #28c093;
  height: 5em;
}

.navbar-collapse collapse .navbar-right ul li a {
  color: #3234cd;
  background-color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}

.navbar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #ff0;
}

.projectName a {
  color: #3234cd;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  padding-top: 1.1em;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Georgia, serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.projectName a:hover {
  color: #1d5fd7;
}


/***h1***/

h1 {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Georgia, serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #3234cd;
  text-align: center;
}

.img-responsive hoian {
  display: inline-block;
  float: center;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 2em;
  border: red;
}

body>.container {
  padding: 60px 15px 0;
}

#my-navbar a {
  background: aqua;
}

/***footer***/

footer {
  padding-top: 1em;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Georgia, serif;
  color: #3234cd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Julinsecommerce</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>

<body>

  <!--navbar starts here-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#my-navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        <div class="projectName navbar-brand">
          <a href="./index">ДЖУЛИН</a>
        </div>
        <!--end projectName -->
      </div>
      <!--end navbar-header -->
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="my-navbar">

        <ul class="navbar-right nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"> <a href="#home"> Home </a> </li>
          <li class="active"> <a href="#about"> About </a></li>
          <li class="active"> <a href="#contact">Contact </a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end nav container-->
  </nav>

  <%= yield %>

    <footer>
      &copy; 2017 Julin
      <p> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
        <a href=#> Back to top </a>
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, I somehow thought jquery is in one of the other files... ruby on rails is still very unfamiliar to me.

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow @Julin, If the answer is what you looking for mark it as [Correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for the future readers. Thank you!